# How to make Visual Studio 2008 debugger halt at the line where an error occurs?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

Whenever I am in debug mode my application closes whenever an error has occurred. The expected outcome is for the VS debugger to halt at the line where the error occurs.

I am running VS 2008 on Win 7 Pro x64.

Is there anyone out there with the same issue and has successfully resolved?

Comment: please be more descriptive. What is the error ? Please post a detailed description of your error.

Comment: @Andrew, it's not about the error per se. It's about VS not stopping at the line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your program has stopped should be in the Output window.

If the program simply ended, you can debug it to find out why it stopped too soon.

If not, most likely you're getting an exception that is not trapped.
Go to the menu entry Debug / Exceptions :

[image1 http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/5899/screen001l.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/5899/screen001l.jpg)

And put a check next to the exception. You're most likely getting one of the Win32 Exceptions:

[image2 http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6976/screen002j.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6976/screen002j.jpg)